# Syntaxerror in CREATE TABLE without any table creation but in procedure creation

Tags: sql, ms-access, procedure

I'm using Microsoft Access 2003, new to SQL tho. I have no idea why this wouldn't work, google won't help me either. The table "K_Lehrer" exists, and the code I have here is the only thing I wrote.

My code is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testprocedure
    AS  
    BEGIN  
       SELECT * FROM K_Lehrer
    END
```

Error (translated):

> syntax error in create table statement

[error with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWc0y.jpg)

Comment: Exactly that is my problem, the error is about some table creation without me actually creating a table at any point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Access 2003 does not support stored procedure as sql.
You can use [Microsoft Access Procedure Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-procedure-statement-microsoft-access-sql) for creating the same